# How to put "login_check" behind firewall in symfony2 security config

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have this in my config

```
firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check

            logout:
                path:  /logout
```

My problem is if i use this then i get

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check" error
```

Everything works ok if use

```
 pattern:    ^/
```

Symfony decumentation says to put login_check behind firewall and i don't know how can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly mentioned `Symfony decumentation says to put login_check behind firewall and i don't know how can i do that` - this means, that you have to define your login_check in this way:

```
       check_path:  /admin/login_check
```

Source - [Common Pitfalls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form) section